# GROUP CONCAT some distinct some not

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, distinct, group-concat

I have a table

```
company   invest_type  date  round
----------------------------------
A         regular      2011  
A         regular      2011  
A         regular      2012  
A         special      2010  abcd
A         special      2010  abcd

B         regular      2011  
B         regular      2011  
B         regular      2012  
B         special      2010  cdcd
B         special      2010  zzzz

C         regular      2012  
C         regular      2012  
C         special      2010  
C         special      2010
```

I want to display them like this

```
company  dates
A        2010,2011,2011,2012
B        2010,2010,2011,2011,2012
C        2010,2012,2012
```

That is, special investments dates are deduped(usually assigned rounds) but regular investments are not.

I've tried `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT date,invest_type) but it doesn't come close.
Basically I want to grab distinct date values from 'date' as long as round is not 'null' in that case I want repeated values. If round is present, dedupe based on round, if not assume all special investments are the same round and dedupe them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subquery to replace the null rounds in regular investments with a counter, so that the rows will by unique, and then use `SELECT DISTINCT` to de-dupe everything else. Then use `GROUP_CONCAT` on this.

```
SELECT company, GROUP_CONCAT(date ORDER BY date) AS dates
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
               company, date,
               CASE WHEN round IS NOT NULL THEN round
                    WHEN invest_type = 'regular' THEN @counter := @counter + 1
                    ELSE null
               END AS round
    FROM investments
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @counter := 0) AS var) AS x
GROUP BY company
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c2a03/6)

Answer (score 0):

You can perform the deduplication in an inline view, and the `group_concat()` in an outer query, like so:

```
select
  company,
  group_concat(`date` order by `date` ASC separator ',') as dates
from (
  select distinct company, `date`
  from my_table
  where invest_type = 'special'
  union all
  select company, `date`
  from my_table
  where invest_type != 'special'
) dedup
group by company
```

Comment: This will combine the `cdcd` and `zzzz` rows into one entry.

Comment: @Barmar, yes, it will.  That was intentional, but as I review the question it appears not to be what the OP wanted after all.  It could be resolved by adding `round` to the select lists of the two component queries of the inline view.